# JSF: the binding value of selectOneMenu never get set

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I have a selectOneMenu look like this

```
<h:form>
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{CreateAds.selectedOwnerId}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a Owner" itemValue=""/>
      <f:selectItems value="#{CreateAds.availableOwner}" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Here is my `CreateAds` `ViewScoped` bean

```
@ViewScoped
public class CreateAds extends View {        

private List<SelectItem> availableOwner = null;

private String selectedOwnerId = null;

public CreateAds() {
}

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    availableOwner = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    List<User> users = scholarEJB.findSponsorAndAdmin();
    for(User u : users){
        availableOwner.add(new SelectItem(u.getId().toString(), u.getFname() + " " + u.getLname()));
    }
} 
//getters and setters
}
```

The list display correctly, but when value `selectedOwnerId` attribute never got set. Its value is **null**. Here is the html my code generated

```
<select size="1" name="j_idt50:j_idt51">
  <option value="">Select a Owner</option>
  <option value="19102">Harry Pham</option>
  <option value="27101">Thomas Chang</option>
  <option value="27562">Hao Shen Lin</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere a submit button/script and/or an action method. Isn't this just oversimplification?

Comment: @BalusC: I just realize that as well. I have the selectOneMenu on a different form of my `commandButton`. So silly. If you can put your comment into a simple quick answer, so I can accept it. Thank you :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a command button/link in the **same** form as the dropdown.